# wordpress radio button and dropdown

Tags: wordpress, memberpress

I have membership site with 48 pages (memberpress).

I want to have a main page in which I would like to have dropdown and radio button selectors.

When user clicks relevant page should load.

Can I accomplish it with a plug-in as I do not know web programming.

Comment: Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would want to search for a filtering plugin like [Search & Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/). [Relevanssi](https://www.relevanssi.com/) also lets you connect certain search parameters to direct results. If you are using custom post types (should also work with memberpress) [this guide](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-ajax-taxonomies-filter-in-wordpress-search/) could be worth a look.